# BQ E4.5 adb fails

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, phone, adb

With an Ubuntu phone BQ E4.5, I have enabled the Developer mode and connected through USB.
when I issue: `adb devices` it returns nothing and `adb shell` returns "error: device not found"

Whether I unmount or not the device does not change anything. (note that I can see the phone fine with MTP...)

I can see the device with `lsusb`, but it has no description:

Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2a47:0c02

Any pointer please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using on your desktop?

Comment: 14.04. Solution below worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

adb shows a device only when it knows the vendor of the device.
The vendor of the bq E4.5 seems not known by default.

To change that edit or create the file `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` and add the following line

```
0x2a47
```

That is the vendor id of the bq E4.5.

Restart the adb server after you edited the file

```
sudo adb kill-server;  sudo adb start-server
```

You can find out the id by yourself with `lsusb`. 
(I made the id bold so you can see where to look for it in the lsusb output)

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID **2a47**:0c02
```

(Or you could execute `lsusb -v` and look for the *idVendor* field.)

Comment: where is he android.ini file, do i create it and if yes where??

Comment: The android.ini file has to be in your home directory in the folder .android. If the file does not exist you have to create it.

Comment: but in my pc or android??

Comment: Ah, sorry. On your PC.

Comment: Also note the usage of `sudo` is required when restarting the adv server, even if there is no error without.

Comment: One  point for `lsusb -v`