# Ubuntu SDK fails to SSH to BQ Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, qt-creator

I'm using the Ubuntu SDK/QT Creator and trying to deploy an HTML5 application to my Ubuntu Phone. QT Creator can see the device correctly and I can SSH into the phone manually from the command line. When I try to publish the application to the phone it gives an error saying the connection is refused.

The log on the Devices tab shows that QT Creator is talking to the phone correctly via SSH. However, the logs say that port forwarding is being used and replacing port 22 with 10000. When I look at the Device tab of the Options window the settings for the Ubuntu device are locked to SSHing on port 10000 (i.e. the option to change it is greyed out). Pressing the button to test the connection fails with a connection refused error).

I've tried adding a new device on the Devices tab of the Options window and using port 22 and the test passes. However, I'm only able to add new devices of type 'generic linux device' and not an Ubuntu device. This means that I can't use it as a kit to publish applications with because the Click package creation stuff is only available for Ubuntu device kits.

Long story short, how do I get the phone to accept connections on port 10000 or how can I change the settings of QT Creator.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have your phone unlocked and with screen on when you try that? QT Creator can only talk to the phone when the screen is on and unlocked.

Comment: Yes the phone is unlocked. I can SSH in on port 22 but QT Creator always tries to connect on port 10000 and won't let me change the settings

Comment: Does the access via adb work? If not maybe adb does not know the vendor of your device. I don't know if QT Creator uses this info as well so I would make sure that adb can see your device. If adb does not see your device you can follow this instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/601324/bq-e4-5-adb-fails/601364#601364. Antoher thing: Did you turn on delevoper mode on your device in the settings? Im pretty sure that developer mode has to be on otherwise QT creator can not use the device.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by modifying 
/home/[user]/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/devices.xml.

original:

```
<value type="QString" key="Host">[10.0.1.9]:24</value>
<value type="int" key="SshPort">10000</value>
```

modified:

```
<value type="QString" key="Host">[10.0.1.9]</value>
<value type="int" key="SshPort">22</value>
```

At first I fixed this problem by modifying sshd_config on the device and adding port 10000, but that stopped working.  I'd like to know the correct way to fix this issue...